# SQL: join table showing null value as well

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table like this:

table1:

```
id | item_name | entered_by | modify_by
1  | banana    |     2      |    1
2  | apple     |     4      |    3
3  | orance    |     1      |    1
4  | pineapple |     5      |    3
5  | grape     |     6      |    1
```

table2:

```
id | username 
1  | admin
2  | jack
3  | danny
4  | dummy
5  | john
6  | peter
```

the query is work fine to select if the entered_by or modify_by do have value:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.item_name,
  t2enteredBy.username enteredBy,
  t2modifyBy.username modifyBy
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2enteredBy ON t1.entered_by = t2enteredBy.id
JOIN table2 t2modifyBy ON t1.modify_by = t2modifyBy.id
```

**problem**: if one of the modifiy_by or entered_by field have null value, the row is now showing out, i need it to show it out as '-' if it has null value rather than hide the row completely.

[SQLFIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4c86/1)

Comment: use left join instead of join

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`s and `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.item_name,
  COALESCE(t2enteredBy.username, '-') enteredBy,
  COALESCE(t2modifyBy.username, '-') modifyBy
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2enteredBy ON t1.entered_by = t2enteredBy.id
LEFT JOIN table2 t2modifyBy ON t1.modify_by = t2modifyBy.id
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c3c2/1).

You need a `left join` to return those rows with `null` values. Then the `coalesce` will make sure that they are replaced by the given string if they are `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.item_name,ifnull(t2enteredBy.username,'-') enteredBy,
  ifnull(t2modifyBy.username,'-') modifyBy
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2enteredBy ON t1.entered_by = t2enteredBy.id
LEFT JOIN table2 t2modifyBy ON t1.modify_by = t2modifyBy.id
```

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4c86/4)

Comment: This will not handle null values. The OP was asking for if the values is null then '-'

Comment: thanks Arion, just update the answer with the fiddle

Comment: I would most probably use COALESCE. Because you do not know it he uses MYSQL

Comment: he tag the question with Mysql

Comment: Okay sorry did not see that

Comment: dont worry about the null, i do a manual checker on my code rather than in sql